# variable doesn't upgrade as parameter

Tags: c#, methods

My variable `Index` doesn't change when I passed it as parameter in  the method:

```
int Index = 0;

void Method (int Index_)
{
    Index_++;
}

Method(Index);
Console.WriteLine(Index);
```

The console print 0 despite the index should increase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, when you pass a primitive (`int`, `char`, `float`, etc) parameter into a function, the function creates a local copy of that variable. if you want to pass the parameter by reference you can use the `ref` keyword, which basically tells the function to use the original variable rather than creating a new local copy of it.

You can use it like this:

```cs
int Index = 0;

void Method (ref int Index_)
{
    Index_++;
}

Method(ref Index);
Console.WriteLine(Index);
```